# Html.ValidationSummary DisplayMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Is it possible to set the DisplayMode from `ValidationSummaryDisplayMode.BulletList` to `ValidationSummaryDisplayMode.SingleParagraph` in Razor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get around this by overwriting the list items style for the validation summary to none.

```
.validation-summary-errors ul
{
    padding: 0;
}

.validation-summary-errors li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #f14c38 !important;
}
```

But I have not found a way to change the list into a paragraph.  You could always put the list inside a paragraph and then

```
<p>
    @Html.ValidationSummary();
</p>
```